# Detecting changes in Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Is it possible to be notified when data is updated in Cassandra?
I.e. when changes to a node have been replicated in from another node?

Could I do this directly using Gossip, or is there a higher level abstraction?

Comment: fyi: i have since found a third party implementation that uses Aspects to intercept the write methods in Cassandra - too fragile methinks. Also some implementations of asynch triggers that were contributed back, but do not appear to have made it into a release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Gossip isn't something to be relied on. The Cassandra nodes themselves don't rely on it for guarantees. (e.g. if a node is down then updates are queued for an hour only). This is also why you need to run `nodetool repair` regularly.

Neither does Cassandra have triggers.

I recommend you do update tracking in your application.